# Commits are shown as done by a different user Xcode

Tags: xcode, version-control, commit

I just noticed the my latest commits are shown with a different user name in Xcode. How could that have happened and how to fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the git author details by going to `Preferences` > `Source Control` > `Git`

[image]

Comment: The thing is that I didn't set it up ..fields are empty, so yes, I can set it up to my name and mail but, up to a few day ago it was committing already to that. How come it switched? I didn't do anything I can remember of..
Dough after I changed it commit stayed to previous author name..

Comment: I guess then you have [set the username via git config](https://help.github.com/en/github/using-git/setting-your-username-in-git)

Comment: I sure don't remember changing anything .. Anyways.. `git config user.name` returns the correct name previously shown in commits..
Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: You're welcome. Some other things that I would look into would be the `Me` card in your Contacts and the `Organization` field in your project's file inspector (though I think they are only used for the copyright info at the top of your source files)

Comment: Well, it actually worked specifying the author name  in the preferences, but I realised that it was actually using `Me` card as the author name is the same I have for my computer. I can tell because in `Organisation` is spelled with capital letters.
Finally..solved. Thank you very much again.